# Recognition of numbers on screen,digital numbers

Tags: windows, opencv

I have doing my research on recognize the digital numbers which is the numbers displayed on 7-segment  by using camera to capture ,but ocr library has limited to it .where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SimpleCV](http://simplecv.org/) is an open source Python framework for building computer vision applications. With it, you get access to several high-powered computer vision libraries such as OpenCV – without having to first learn about bit depths, file formats, color spaces, buffer management, eigenvalues, or matrix versus bitmap storage. This is computer vision made easy.

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is an open source computer vision and machine learning software library. OpenCV was built to provide a common infrastructure for computer vision applications and to accelerate the use of machine perception in the commercial products. It has C++, C, Python, Java and MATLAB interfaces and supports Windows, Linux, Android and Mac OS.